# ¿Es posible que un evento de fullcalendar deje de estar colorido en las horas que no se trabaja?

Tags: javascript, php, html, base-de-datos, fullcalendar

Estoy trabajando con fullcalendar v6
Quiero hacer que los eventos que inserte, no estén coloridos en las horas en que no se trabaja, adjuntare una imagen para ser mas claro.

Mi rango de horas de trabajo es de 07:00 a 17:00, entonces quiero que solamente este colorido el evento entre el anterior rango de horar.

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.
Para que podamos ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, muestranos cuale

Comment: Cuando devuelvas el `Json` con todos los eventos corta en dos, los eventos que ocupen las horas de descanso. Easy money